# Angular 5: accessing variable in component from loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I am porting some code from an AngularJS component into an Angular 5 component.

I have an array of objects loaded into a variable `productlist`.

In my old controller, I created a second variable as an empty array, `showcaselist`.

I run a `forEach` loop on the `productlist` to find all items that meet a condition (`item.acf.product_slide.length > 0`) and push them into the `showcaselist`.  I then display these items in my template.

Logging to console shows the data is coming in, and the `if` statement works, but I keep getting a console error:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.showcaselist')`

Here is the whole component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'pb-ds-showcaseindex',
  templateUrl: './showcaseindex.component.html'
})
export class ShowcaseindexComponent implements OnInit {

  productlist;
  showcaselist = [];

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.productlist = this._route.snapshot.data.showcases;
    this.itemsWithSlides();

  }

  itemsWithSlides = function () {
    this.productlist.forEach(function (item) {
      if (item.acf.product_slide.length > 0) {
        this.showcaselist.push(item);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: `itemsWithSlides = function....` is not correct syntax.

Comment: @Phax The syntax is correct, just unusual.  Instead of declaring a method in the ES6 style it assigns a function to that property name.

Comment: Yes, we did it all the time in ES5.  I'm still getting used to ES6/TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an arrow function instead - the current function is creating a new `this` that refers to a different object.

```
  itemsWithSlides = () => {
    this.productlist.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.acf.product_slide.length > 0) {
        this.showcaselist.push(item);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks.  Arrow functions are new to me.  I figured it had something to do with the "this", though.

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten the whole thing up using the `filter()` function

```
export class ShowcaseindexComponent implements OnInit {
  productlist;
  showcaselist = [];

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.productlist = this._route.snapshot.data.showcases;
    this.showcaseList = this.productList.filter(item => item.acf.product_slide.length > 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  I had no knowledge of the `filter()` function.  Is that an ES6 thing?

Comment: Yep! With `.map()`, `.reduce()`, and `.filter()`, you can cut out most of your `for` loops.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productlist = this._route.snapshot.data.showcases;
    this.itemsWithSlides(this.productList);
  }

private itemsWithSlides(productList) {
  if (productList) {
    productList.forEach(item => {
      if (item && item.acf.product_slide.length > 0) {
        this.showcaseList.push(item);
      }
    });
  }
}
```